# How to use LINQ to get an object from List of objects matching option from List of options

Tags: c#, linq

I have class `Accounts` where each `Account` has

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Currency { get; set; }
```

along side with other properties which are irrelevant to the question.

I also have a `List<string> currencies` with string names of different currencies which are inserted based on a certain logic. So what I want to do is given a `List<Accounts> accounts` to get the `Id` of the account where the cobndition is that I have to check all `accounts` if the match `currencies[0]` if there are no accounts in this currencies, then proceed to `currencies[1]` and so on, until some account has tha same currency. The important is to keep the order of currencies in the list. I want the account with a currency which is standing closer to the begining of the list.

Right now I have this :

```
string accId = accounts.Where(c => c.Currency.Equals(currencies[0])).FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

So one option is to put this inside some kind of loop so I can change the currnecies index. However I wonder if this can be made purely with LINQ?

Comment: Can you post the logic you use to populate the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string accId = 
    (from currency in currencies 
    from account in accounts
    where account.Currency.Equals(currency)
    select account.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Linq is more fun to use this way! ;)

**EDIT:** If you dont like the syntax, here is the alternative version:

```
var accId = currencies
    .SelectMany(currency => accounts
        .Where(account => account.Currency.Equals(currency))).FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I0wzkH)

Comment: How does this take into account the order in which items have been added to the list?

Comment: Well, I'm conciusly avoiding this syntax, however I'm gonna accept the answer if it's working. However can you make it fun for me too by using LINQ2Entities since I want to keep consistancy in my code.

Comment: from works the same way as foreach does. So they should be added in the same order. EDIT: Give me a sec, I'll convert.

Comment: Here you go, I wrote it on top of my head, so forgive me if there are tiny errors.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting some sort of exception but also `accId` value is the query itself or something that looks pretty much like it.

Comment: Yeap, at first it was just `Select` with `SelectMany` it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @Aron `accounts.Where(a => currencies.Contains(a.Currency)).FirstOrDefault().Id` doesn't take the order of `currencies` into account. But I get your point regarding unnecessary joins. With that and readability in mind, agree that LVBen's answer is the best.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't give you a list, but it is more efficient than getting the entire list:

```
var id = currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
         .Where(account => account != null)
         .FirstOrDefault().Id;
```

If you want the entire list, do this:

```
var accs = currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
         .Where(account => account != null)
         .ToList();
```

If you want just the IEnumerable, then do this:

```
var accs = currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
         .Where(account => account != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index as the sort order (note that, like your example, this will throw if there's no match)...

```
var accountId = currencies.Select((c, i) => new { Currency = c, SortOrder = i })
    .Join(accounts, 
          c => c.Currency, 
          a => a.Currency, 
          (c, a) => new { Account = a, SortOrder = c.SortOrder })
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
    .First()
    .Account.Id;
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6qVkI0)